# Test a state machine using spock framework

Tags: java, groovy, junit, spock

I have built a state machine in Java and I am trying to unit test the same with spock framework with all the possible combinations of the state that the input can make a transition. I prefer to capture the possible combinations in a data table but I am facing a challenge in iterating a list of values as input in the data table. Please refer to the below test :

```
@Unroll("#current state can successfully transit to #next")
def "Validate the successful transition of the state machine"() {
    given:
    when:
    def result = current.canTransitionTo(next)
    then:
    result == true

    where:
    current | next
    STATE_A | STATE_B // Works 
    STATE_A | STATE_C // Works
    STATE_A | [STATE_B, STATE_C] // This approach won't work since canTransitionTo() is not expecting an arraylist
}
```

The first two approaches work, however I am searching for a way to make the third approach working where the spock framework need to iterate through all the possible next values since canTransitionTo() is designed to take a single state and not arraylist and validate the result.

Has anyone done something similar. I'm bit new to spock, but wanted to learn if the third approach could be made possible to test, else please suggest a better way to test this state machine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like you said:

> This approach won't work since canTransitionTo() is not expecting an arraylist

Therefore, you need to make sure to iterate over the list. Thanks to Groovy goodness, you have convenience methods for that. How about `next.every { current.canTransitionTo(it) }`?

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q68674245

import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.lang.Unroll

import static de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q68674245.StateMachineTest.StateMachine.*

class StateMachineTest extends Specification {
  @Unroll("#current state can successfully transit to #next")
  def "Validate the successful transition of the state machine"() {
    expect:
    next.every { current.canTransitionTo(it) }

    where:
    current | next
    STATE_A | STATE_B
    STATE_A | STATE_C
    STATE_A | [STATE_B, STATE_C]
    START   | [STATE_A, STATE_B, STATE_C]
    STATE_C | [STATE_B, START]  // fails, because START is a forbidden target state
  }

  static enum StateMachine {
    START, STATE_A, STATE_B, STATE_C

    boolean canTransitionTo(StateMachine stateMachine) {
      println "transition $this -> $stateMachine"
      return stateMachine != START
    }
  }
}
```

You can even go further and allow iterables on both ends of the transition:

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q68674245

import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.lang.Unroll

import static de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q68674245.StateMachineTest.StateMachine.*

class StateMachineTest extends Specification {
  @Unroll("#current can transit to #next")
  def "Validate successful transition of the state machine"() {
    expect:
    current.every { from -> next.every { to -> from.canTransitionTo(to) } }

    where:
    current                            | next
    [START, STATE_A, STATE_B, STATE_C] | [STATE_A, STATE_B, STATE_C]
  }

  @Unroll("#current must not transit to #next")
  def "Validate failed state machine transition"() {
    expect:
    current.every { from -> next.every { to -> !from.canTransitionTo(to) } }

    where:
    current                            | next
    [START, STATE_A, STATE_B, STATE_C] | START
  }

  static enum StateMachine {
    START, STATE_A, STATE_B, STATE_C

    boolean canTransitionTo(StateMachine stateMachine) {
      println "transition $this -> $stateMachine"
      return stateMachine != START
    }
  }
}
```

P.S.: In the above case, you actually do not need `where` blocks, if the data tables only consist of single lines. But I am assuming that your state machine is a bit more complex than my example and you need to specify more differentiated cases.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But just thought of asking for an enhancement as well to my real use case, how can I add an extra column to  represent actionedBy which represents a system and conditionally invoke the method without an if clause.  Ex : System1 |STATE_A | STATE_B invokes canTransitToSystem1State() and System2 |STATE_A | STATE_B invokes canTransitToSystemsState().  I tried with multiple when, then coditions but it didn't work

Comment: I do not understand your follow-up question. I think I correctly answered the original question already and explained even more than you asked. So please, accept and upvote my answer and ask a new question. But this time, post a full [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), like I did in my answer. I need something I can compile and run. I need complete classes: class under test, dependency classes (if any), test. Then I understand better what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `combinations()` to generate the different combinations you want.

```
class ASpec extends Specification {
    def "can transition"() {
        expect: true
        where:
        [from, to] << 
            [["STATE_A"], ["STATE_B", "STATE_C"]].combinations() + 
            [["STATE_B", "STATE_C"], ["STATE_C", "STATE_D"]].combinations()
    }
}
```

this will produce

```
╷
└─ Spock ✔
   └─ ASpec ✔
      └─ can transition ✔
         ├─ can transition [from: STATE_A, to: STATE_B, #0] ✔
         ├─ can transition [from: STATE_A, to: STATE_C, #1] ✔
         ├─ can transition [from: STATE_B, to: STATE_C, #2] ✔
         ├─ can transition [from: STATE_C, to: STATE_C, #3] ✔
         ├─ can transition [from: STATE_B, to: STATE_D, #4] ✔
         └─ can transition [from: STATE_C, to: STATE_D, #5] ✔
```

You can try it online in the [groovy webconsole](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?codez=eJx1jkEKgzAQRfc5xTCrlkoPIG5S2xPoTkJJ40gDNZEkpULx7o1iFSn9q_n_M29GPaT3wIuOFFAfyNQeRqMbrWTQ1sCbQVRNDaCSBoKTxuuxwd1-LkdRH7dCGvsnLeHrTo7SxVaNs20CwQrIMljiqaqwKHl5uXIUCXzNCROYxxyFOCrb3rSZ_vLx-uEPY7u24vI1P__iJtbABsY21A9dYEx4).